# Laravel Controller: translating an SQL SELECT DISTINCT statement inside a function

Tags: sql, laravel, select, controller, distinct

**Table List:**

[image: 1]

Here is the SQL as mentioned in the title:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (hbg.group_id)
    hbg.group_id,
    hbg.id AS id,
    hbg.group_name,
    hbg.group_description,
    hbg.group_type_id,
    hbgt.group_type_name,
    hbg.category_id,
    hbg.effective_start_datetime,
    hbg.created_by,
    hbg.created_datetime,
    hbg.archived_by,
    hbg.archived_datetime
FROM hms_bbr_group hbg
LEFT JOIN hms_bbr_group_type hbgt
    ON hbg.group_type_id = hbgt.group_type_id
ORDER BY
    hbg.group_id,
    hbg.id DESC;
```

test in pgAdmin: (only selecting distinct id)

[image: 2]

I am trying to translate this inside a function in my Laravel Controller

**Function:**

```
public function fetchgroup(){
    $all_groups = HmsBbrGroup::join('hms_bbr_group_type', 'hms_bbr_group.group_type_id', '=', 'hms_bbr_group_type.group_type_id')
                               ->distinct('group_id')
                               ->orderBy('group_id', 'ASC', 'id', 'DESC')->get();
    return response()->json([
        'all_groups'=>$all_groups,
    ]);
}
```

The code above works differently though, the screenshot below is the output. The rows shown are different:

[image: 3]

I tried changing up the orderBy but the rows shown are still not the correct `id` (the highest value `id` on every `group_id`)

any help would be appreciated thanks

**UPDATE:**

tried tweaking the function abit but the output is exactly the same as the screenshot:

```
    $all_groups = HmsBbrGroup::leftJoin('hms_bbr_group_type', 'hms_bbr_group.group_type_id', '=', 'hms_bbr_group_type.group_type_id')
                               ->distinct('hms_bbr_group.group_id')
                               ->orderBy('group_id', 'ASC', 'id', 'DESC')->get();
```

**UPDATE 2**

I tried changing up the distinct in the function but the code below does not work as intended as well

```
    $all_groups = HmsBbrGroup::join('hms_bbr_group_type', 'hms_bbr_group.group_type_id', '=', 'hms_bbr_group_type.group_type_id')
                        ->selectRaw('DISTINCT ON (group_id),     
                        hms_bbr_group.group_id,
                        hms_bbr_group.id AS id,
                        hms_bbr_group.group_name,
                        hms_bbr_group.group_description,
                        hms_bbr_group.group_type_id,
                        hms_bbr_group_type.group_type_name,
                        hms_bbr_group.category_id,
                        hms_bbr_group.effective_start_datetime,
                        hms_bbr_group.created_by,
                        hms_bbr_group.created_datetime,
                        hms_bbr_group.archived_by,
                        hms_bbr_group.archived_datetime')
                        ->orderBy('group_id', 'ASC', 'id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: dd? also $all_groups is for my forms, It should not matter since I just need the select to be working. The 3rd screenshot is the output when using $all_groups.

Comment: That's the output of your view but not the raw data. Since we don't know your codebase as well as you do, we need to wrap our head around that first and this often times works easier with raw data.

Comment: You're asking what `dd()` is? It's a [helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dd) provided by Laravel that "dumps" and "dies" afterwards.

Comment: I think there is a problem with join. In SQL, you applied left join. But, in Laravel you applied inner join. you can try with leftJoin.

Comment: @BappiSaha thanks for the tip, but the output is exactly the same after doin leftJoin

Comment: @shaedrich apologies, I have no idea where to put dd() and how to output it

Comment: `HmsBbrGroup::dd()->leftJoin('hms_bbr_group_type', 'hms_bbr_group.group_type_id', '=', 'hms_bbr_group_type.group_type_id')
                               ->distinct('hms_bbr_group.group_id')
                               ->orderBy('group_id', 'ASC', 'id', 'DESC')->get();`

Comment: where can I see the dd() output?